# Automatically close an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox

I am currently using FancyBox (http://fancybox.net/) to display a page on my website. It works amazing and as it should but I want it to close automatically as soon as X number of seconds pass. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript

```
setTimeout("$.fancybox.close();", 5000); // 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
```

Code to add to your FancyBox options

```
onComplete: function() { setTimeout("$.fancybox.close();", 5000); }
```

Example

```
$("SELECTOR").fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    onComplete: function() { setTimeout("$.fancybox.close();", 5000); }
});
```